# SplitButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, split-button

Does anyone have a coded implementation of SplitButton?

I've tried searching some implementations but none of them work. (e.g. [`JSplitButton`](http://code.google.com/p/jsplitbutton/)).

Comment: Every implementation I've seen doesn't transpose will across UIs

Comment: what's wrong with it? Note I didn't try the one you linked to - but for any reasonable suggestion it would be useful to know waht exactly you aren't satisfied with :-)

Comment: I can't click the arrow button. I just run the included demo and it doesn't work. Try it.

Comment: For anyone searching for a simple single-file implementation in 2020. I found one originally posted by [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) and modified it to work for me with [FlatLaf](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/) L&F, but it seems to work rather well with others too. [Link to StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66303093/3452003) [![Component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAMue.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAMue.png)

Answer (score 5):

Demo not working != splitButton not working :-)

```
splitButton = new JSplitButton("Split Button Demo");
splitButton.setPopupMenu(jPopupMenu2);
add(splitButton);
```

(Note: this is *not* a recommendation of that particular splitButton implementation, just a reminder that you should be a bit more careful in evaluating the projects you are finding. If you can't for some reason, you might consider using a commercial product, like Synthetica or JIDE, just to name two)

Comment: After reading the answer, I wanted to ask "why wouldn't you recommend it?". But right now, after actually reading the source, and seeing how it's done... I have my answer. No proper UI class, no proper size handling (putting it in a BoxLayout gives funny results), no actual separation of the "pressed" or hover state. It's really a basic hack, done in one class. Well, off to improve that myself!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). They work for more than just simple drop down, but it should do the trick.

Comment: It seems many (including me) are not familar with this feature. Could you give an example?