# Does Java (swing) have a such button?

Tags: java, swing

At example libre office has button with drop down menu, but it isn't combobox:

[image: Button Snapshot]

Does Swing have analog or something similar?

Comment: It's a SplitButton. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646290/splitbutton-in-java

Answer (score 2):

There's no SplitButton implementation provided by Java. I provided a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646290/splitbutton-in-java) to another question on this site in my comment on potential implementations and would add that Jidesoft has also an implementation of a SplitButton in their open source [JIDE Common Layer](https://github.com/jidesoft/jide-oss), check the licenses first.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can easily achieve it by **wrapping an ImageIcon into a Button**.
(`arrow_down.png` is the downwards pointing, black arrow)

```
button = new JButton();  
button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/icons/arrow_down.png")));  
button.setBorderPainted(false);  
button.setFocusPainted(false);  
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Comment: I think that the question is about the drop down menu of the button and not the icon in the button?!