# How do you create Swing "dropdown" buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, split-button

How does NetBeans create those buttons that have the little down arrow to the right of the main button which when pressed brings up a menu?  The NetBeans "Debug Project button is one example.  Are they two separate `JButton` components?  Just how are they constructed?

Comment: Sounds like a `JComboBox` ..  On 2nd thoughts, see also ['split button'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11646290/418556).

Comment: More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20splitbutton).

Answer (score -1):

It's called a JComboBox I believe. You can find some documentation on how to make comboboxes here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html