# Button with image, text, arrow and menu

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a button that has an icon with text on the top and arrow on the corner. Upon clicking on it, a menu is displayed. I was able to achieve all of above except for the arrow part. I know I can have an an image file that has the icon and arrow saved in one png file. However, I don't want to alter the icon file. Here is the code I have so far.

How can I add an arrow ( whether programmtically or from another arrow image file to the button)

```
public class JButtonMenu extends JToggleButton {

    JPopupMenu popup;

    public JButtonMenu(ImageIcon img, String title, String []list) {
        super(name);
        this.popup = new JPopupMenu();
        this.buttonId = buttonId;
        this.setMenuList(list);  //This is another method 
        setIcon(img);
        setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
        setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    public void setMenuList(String[]list){
        if(list == null){
            return;
        }
        for(String item:list){
            popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction(item) {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
                int index= popup.getComponentIndex(menuItem);
                menuItemListener.itemSelectedListener(buttonId,index, menuItem.getText());
            }
        }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352707/actions-inside-of-another-action-like-netbeans/36353275#36353275)?

Comment: Thats using jcombo box. I don't want the selection to be shown on the button.

Comment: No, it's not, it's a custom `JButton` (AKA a split button), `public class SplitButton extends JButton {`, which can do two things, activate the "current" action or show a drop down menu

Comment: Ohhh I dont know where  I was looking before. Thanks for the comment. wow thats a huge class. Is there no piece of code you can put as an answer that would do the job for my code? :)

Comment: I did a stripped down version which focuses only on the painting side of things and the functionality you would need to implement to make it work (and look nice). You can use the full version as bases for working out how to make the popup show up. The full version should work in two ways based on how it's configured, it can execute the default action if the user doesn't click on the arrow or show the popup if they do OR always show the popup regardless of where they click, those were the requirements I was required to implement, so they might no all meet your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a watered down version of [this implementation of a split button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352707/actions-inside-of-another-action-like-netbeans/36353275#36353275) but which focuses on the need for painting an additional image as well as some of the other functionality you'll need to implement to ensure that the original text and icon are offset accurtaly.

[image: Example split button]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                SplitButton btn = new SplitButton();
                btn.setText("This is a split button");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(btn);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SplitButton extends JButton {

        private int separatorSpacing = 4;
        private int splitWidth = 30;
        private int arrowSize = 8;

        private Rectangle splitRectangle;
        private Color arrowColor = Color.BLACK;
        private Color disabledArrowColor = Color.GRAY;
        private Image image;

        public SplitButton() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getInsets() {
            Insets insets = (Insets) super.getInsets().clone();
            insets.right += splitWidth;
            return insets;
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getInsets(Insets insets) {
            Insets insets1 = getInsets();
            insets.left = insets1.left;
            insets.right = insets1.right;
            insets.bottom = insets1.bottom;
            insets.top = insets1.top;
            return insets1;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the separatorSpacing. Separator spacing is the space above and
         * below the separator( the line drawn when you hover your mouse over the
         * split part of the button).
         *
         * @return separatorSpacingimage = null; //to repaint the image with the new
         * size
         */
        public int getSeparatorSpacing() {
            return separatorSpacing;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the separatorSpacing.Separator spacing is the space above and below
         * the separator( the line drawn when you hover your mouse over the split
         * part of the button).
         *
         * @param spacing
         */
        public void setSeparatorSpacing(int spacing) {
            if (spacing != separatorSpacing && spacing >= 0) {
                int old = separatorSpacing;
                this.separatorSpacing = spacing;
                image = null;
                firePropertyChange("separatorSpacing", old, separatorSpacing);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Gets the color of the arrow.
         *
         * @return arrowColor
         */
        public Color getArrowColor() {
            return arrowColor;
        }

        /**
         * Set the arrow color.
         *
         * @param color
         */
        public void setArrowColor(Color color) {
            if (arrowColor != color) {
                Color old = arrowColor;
                this.arrowColor = color;
                image = null;
                firePropertyChange("arrowColor", old, arrowColor);
                repaint();
            }
        }

        /**
         * gets the disabled arrow color
         *
         * @return disabledArrowColor color of the arrow if no popup attached.
         */
        public Color getDisabledArrowColor() {
            return disabledArrowColor;
        }

        /**
         * sets the disabled arrow color
         *
         * @param color color of the arrow if no popup attached.
         */
        public void setDisabledArrowColor(Color color) {
            if (disabledArrowColor != color) {
                Color old = disabledArrowColor;
                this.disabledArrowColor = color;
                image = null; //to repaint the image with the new color
                firePropertyChange("disabledArrowColor", old, disabledArrowColor);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Splitwidth is the width of the split part of the button.
         *
         * @return splitWidth
         */
        public int getSplitWidth() {
            return splitWidth;
        }

        /**
         * Splitwidth is the width of the split part of the button.
         *
         * @param width
         */
        public void setSplitWidth(int width) {
            if (splitWidth != width) {
                int old = splitWidth;
                this.splitWidth = width;
                firePropertyChange("splitWidth", old, splitWidth);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        /**
         * gets the size of the arrow.
         *
         * @return size of the arrow
         */
        public int getArrowSize() {
            return arrowSize;
        }

        /**
         * sets the size of the arrow
         *
         * @param size
         */
        public void setArrowSize(int size) {
            if (arrowSize != size) {
                int old = arrowSize;
                this.arrowSize = size;
                image = null; //to repaint the image with the new size
                firePropertyChange("setArrowSize", old, arrowSize);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Gets the image to be drawn in the split part. If no is set, a new image
         * is created with the triangle.
         *
         * @return image
         */
        public Image getImage() {
            if (image == null) {
                Graphics2D g = null;
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(arrowSize, arrowSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                g = (Graphics2D) img.createGraphics();
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
                g.setColor(isEnabled() ? arrowColor : disabledArrowColor);
                //this creates a triangle facing right >
                g.fillPolygon(new int[]{0, 0, arrowSize / 2}, new int[]{0, arrowSize, arrowSize / 2}, 3);
                g.dispose();
                //rotate it to face downwards
                img = rotate(img, 90);
                BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                g = (Graphics2D) dimg.createGraphics();
                g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
                g.drawImage(img, null, 0, 0);
                g.dispose();
                for (int i = 0; i < dimg.getHeight(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dimg.getWidth(); j++) {
                        if (dimg.getRGB(j, i) == Color.WHITE.getRGB()) {
                            dimg.setRGB(j, i, 0x8F1C1C);
                        }
                    }
                }

                image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(dimg.getSource());
            }
            return image;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param g
         */
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            //Graphics gClone = g.create();//EDIT: Hervé Guillaume
            Color oldColor = g.getColor();
            splitRectangle = new Rectangle(getWidth() - splitWidth, 0, splitWidth, getHeight());
            g.translate(splitRectangle.x, splitRectangle.y);
            int mh = getHeight() / 2;
            int mw = splitWidth / 2;
            g.drawImage(getImage(), mw - arrowSize / 2, mh + 2 - arrowSize / 2, null);
            if (getModel().isRollover() || isFocusable()) {
                g.setColor(UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getColor("Button.background"));
                g.drawLine(1, separatorSpacing + 2, 1, getHeight() - separatorSpacing - 2);
                g.setColor(UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getColor("Button.shadow"));
                g.drawLine(2, separatorSpacing + 2, 2, getHeight() - separatorSpacing - 2);
            }
            g.setColor(oldColor);
            g.translate(-splitRectangle.x, -splitRectangle.y);
        }

        /**
         * Rotates the given image with the specified angle.
         *
         * @param img image to rotate
         * @param angle angle of rotation
         * @return rotated image
         */
        private BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage img, int angle) {
            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();
            BufferedImage dimg = dimg = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getType());
            Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
            g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w / 2, h / 2);
            g.drawImage(img, null, 0, 0);
            return dimg;
        }

    }

}
```

Swing has a well defined and documented painting process, in order to perform custom painting you need to work within the constraints of the API otherwise you will end up with no end ot issues.

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: This is just PERFECT. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

A quick way to do it would be

```
Image img1=imageIcon1.getImage();
Image img2=imageIcon2.getImage();
Graphics g=img1.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(img2, x, y, sizex, sizey, null)
```

where x, y is where you put the second icon (arrow) on the first icon and sizex, sizey is the reduced size of the second icon. You can change these by trying.

You have to have another method

```
public JButtonMenu(ImageIcon imageIcon1, ImageIcon imageIcon2, String title, String []list) {
  // above segment here
  // continue with the rest of the code

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where do I fit the above code in the button (Code above)?

Comment: Don't, don't, don't EVER  use getGraphics, it is not how custom painting works in Swing, once the button is repainted, anything you painted will be erased

Comment: @Snake I did, it's called a `SplitButton` ;)