# Custom popup don't always get focus

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components, focus

I try to basically implement my own combobox for Swing, because JComboBox has some behavior that doesn't suit my requirements and what I need to override is private, so...

Anyway, I tried making a small example to test it out, by extending JComponent with a JTextField inside and a dropdown menu overriding JPopupMenu. I want the dropdown to come down in different cases, but for the test I trigger it with the up and down keys (listening on the text field). The popup has a JList inside a JScrollPane and the problem is that this list doesn't always get focus. I've been fighting with it for days, trying various combinations of show() / setVisible() / requestFocus() and requestFocusInWindow() on every involved component, with and without SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). And in my pasted code is the best attempt, BUT even if the list seem to get focus almost every time, it happens it only selects the item showing it gray (which I assume means it doesnt really have focus). Any ideas?

Oh, and my example doesn't have a main class, it is added to the toolbar of my application if that matters...

Edit: I added a main for testing and of course it seem to work then. So it's just with my real application it doesn't work and it's a pretty complicated gui, to large to post here. It also uses other look and feel, I hope that should not affect focus handling though?

```
package com.sdi.cmsanalyzer.gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CustomComboBox extends JComponent {
    private final JTextField textField;
    private final DropdownMenu dropdown;

    public CustomComboBox() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        textField = new JTextField();

        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    System.out.println("DOWN");
                    showDropdown();
                    dropdown.selectFirstItem();
                } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    System.out.println("UP");
                    showDropdown();
                    dropdown.selectLastItem();
                } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    System.out.println("ENTER");
                }
            }
        });

        add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        dropdown = new DropdownMenu();
    }

    public JTextField getEditor() {
        return this.textField;
    }

    private void showDropdown() {
        dropdown.updateItems(getDropdownItems());

        dropdown.setSize(new Dimension(textField.getWidth(), dropdown.getPreferredSize().height));

        int x = 0;
        int y = textField.getHeight();

        Container parent = textField.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            Point textFieldLocation = textField.getLocation();
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(textFieldLocation, textField);
            SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(textFieldLocation, parent);
            x = textFieldLocation.x;
            y = textFieldLocation.y + textField.getHeight();
        }

        dropdown.show(textField, x, y);
    }

    private String[] getDropdownItems() {
        // Replace with your logic to retrieve the dropdown items
        return new String[]{"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5", "Option 6", "Option 7", "Option 8", "Option 9", "Option 10"};
    }

    private static class DropdownMenu extends JPopupMenu {
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        JScrollPane scrollPane;
        JList<String> list;

        public DropdownMenu() {
            // Create a JList with the list model
            list = new JList<>(listModel);

            // Create a scroll pane and add the list to it
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list,
                    ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                    ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

            add(scrollPane);
            pack();
        }

        public void updateItems(String[] items) {
            listModel.clear();
            for (String item : items) {
                listModel.addElement(item);
            }
        }

        protected void selectFirstItem() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                list.setSelectedIndex(0);
                list.ensureIndexIsVisible(0);
                list.requestFocus();
            });
        }

        protected void selectLastItem() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                list.setSelectedIndex(listModel.getSize() - 1);
                list.ensureIndexIsVisible(listModel.getSize() - 1);
                list.requestFocus();
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create the main frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom ComboBox Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create a toolbar
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();

        // Create an instance of your CustomComboBox
        CustomComboBox customComboBox = new CustomComboBox();

        // Add the CustomComboBox to the toolbar
        toolBar.add(customComboBox);

        // Add the toolbar to the frame
        frame.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Create a center panel
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Set the frame size and make it visible
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Oh, and my example doesn't have a main class, it is added to the toolbar of my application if that matters...* - Yes it matters. We can't test the posted code to see the described behaviour. Also, you should be using `Key Binding` not a KeyListener to control the functionality of your popup.

Comment: *It also uses other look and feel,  I hope that should not affect focus handling though?* - Well that is easy enough to test. Don't use the other LAF. If this code works, then you've proven the basic concept works. The point of creating an [mre] is to isolate the problem in your real application. So this means adding code in the code posted here until it stops working again. Then you know what you changed and can ask a specific question.

Comment: From very old and vague memory, when I was doing simular things, I found `JPopupMenu` unsuited for the task and instead had to use a undecorated`JFrame` [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352707/actions-inside-of-another-action-like-netbeans/36353275#36353275) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535835/button-with-image-text-arrow-and-menu/36536607#36536607)