# JMenuItem with both ActionListener and MouseListener

Tags: java, swing

Well, JMenuItem is designed to work with ActionListener, but sometimes it would be nice to have a right click option as well.
Having both an ActionListener and a MouseListener on a JButton is no problem, but I don't manage to get this done for a JMenuItem. The following code shows a solution to distinguish between left and right click in applying a MouseListener, but I would prefer to handle the left click in a regular ActionListener and only the right click in a MouseListener. Any suggestions?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RMBClickOnMenuItem extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  JMenuItem item1, item2, item3;

  public RMBClickOnMenuItem() {
    super("RMBClickOnMenuItem");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(310, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JMenuBar menuBar= new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu menu= new JMenu("Menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    item1= new JMenuItem("Standard");
    item1.addActionListener(this);
    menu.add(item1);

    item2= new JMenuItem("MouseListener");
    MouseListener[] allMouseL= item2.getMouseListeners();
    for (MouseListener ml: allMouseL)
      item2.removeMouseListener(ml);
    item2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
          System.out.println("Left click");
        else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
          System.out.println("Right click");
        menu.setPopupMenuVisible(false);
      }
    });
    menu.add(item2);

    item3= new JMenuItem("Action- and MouseListener");
    item3.addActionListener(this);
    allMouseL= item3.getMouseListeners();
    for (MouseListener ml: allMouseL)
      item3.removeMouseListener(ml);
    item3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
          System.out.println("Right click on item 3");
        }
        menu.setPopupMenuVisible(false);
      }
    });
    menu.add(item3);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(RMBClickOnMenuItem::new);
  }


  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JMenuItem menuItem= (JMenuItem)event.getSource();
    System.out.println(menuItem.getText());
  }

}
```

Comment: Under what conditions do you think a user might, instinctively, right click a menu item?  In my experience, it doesn't make sense, I can't think of a single system which uses it.  The menu system (`JMenu`/`JMenuItem`) allow for child items automatically, in a way which is intuitive and commonly understood to the user

Comment: @MadProgrammer. It is the request of a customer who is lazy/reluctant to click through submenus or popups.

Comment: Ok - don't compromise standard/understood UX for the sake of ... idiots.  I can't tell you the amount of time I've wasted arguing with, implementing and then removing features that "managers" thought would be useful, but which compromised the UX, were not intuitive to the user or leverage the users understanding/experience with the platform.  So, the problem isn't that the API is limited, it's that the "user" doesn't understand how these systems work and the history the users have with the existing system

Comment: I would consider offering more keyboard short cuts, better, customisable menus and/or toolbars that would allow a individual user the power to configure there system the way that they need it to work.  Leverage the power of the pre-existing `Action` API

Comment: Switching between mouse and keyboard, again, is "too much work" for the customer. I was often requested to implement the right click "shortcut", and they are quite happy so far. - Anyway, thanks for your ideas.

Comment: I've worked across Windows, MacOS, Linux, GUI/text UIs, mobile and tablets and as a developer and user, I can tell you that it's more important to leverage the capabilities of the individual systems and the (many thousands of hours others have put into designing the system for) experience then "invent" something.  I recently downloaded Discord for iOS - if I wasn't required to use it, I would have deleted it, the UX is just that bad and confusing.  Don't satisfy a "lazy" user with features which don't have a bases in established existing workflows, it's a never ending spiral - sorry

Comment: I've had many "lazy" users in my time, they are the minority, but tend to be the most noisy, and they are never satisfied ... and tend to think they are always right ... which more often then not, they aren't.  I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352707/actions-inside-of-another-action-like-netbeans/36353275#36353275) in response to a request to reduce the number of buttons on screen.  The implementation I did was way more complicated, as it could "remember" you actions would set the default action via configuration.

Comment: If they're to lazy to use sub menus, or switch between keyboard or mouse, then they are going to be to lazy (and stupid) to right click a menu item and I would consider that they are using the wrong system, maybe they should be using a touch screen instead :P

Comment: Your SplitButton looks very nice. I will give it a closer look tomorrow and probably suggest it. If it is accepted, I hope I can enter it into the JMenu.

Comment: I agree with MadProgrammer here.  Don’t let end users design user interfaces.  They have no understanding of usability.  (Whenever I hear about end users designing user interfaces, I think of [the Homer Simpson car](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/The_Homer?file=TheHomer.png).)